# Turn OFF Cache for specific file with Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching

I have a page on a site which uses `random()` twig, in Firefox and Chrome it is prevented from working because it gets cached as soon as the page loads.

Is there a way to turn off caching of a particular file via the Apache configs, lets call it `default.html` or even better just turn off caching for the script part of that file but keep caching image files?

I have tried `.htaccess` but this does not work.

The only way currently that allows the script to work is to turn off caching globally via PHP headers:

```
<?php
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
?>
```

But as I only need to turn off caching for an individual page, turning it off for everything seems crazy.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Figured it out, to target a specific file (in this case `index.php`), add this code to the bottom of `.htaccess`

```
<Files index.php>
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</Files>
```

Alternatively to target a specific selection of files, ie. I'd like to cache images but nothing else (files that match `html, htm, js, css, php` will not be cached):

```
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css|php)$">
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</filesMatch>
```

To check the `.htaccess` was being read I entered a few lines of rubbish at the bottom, found out it wasn't being read, renamed it from `htaccess` to `.htaccess` and it worked.

Comment: What about the images that are called on that specific page? Will they still cache?

Comment: Can we comma separate two files?

Comment: I think `Expires` is ignored, when `Cach-Control "max-age ..."` is used: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires